# Twitter Bootstrap styles in Dart polymer template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, polymer

Using polymer.dart, how can I ensure that styles referenced in the consuming page are still available in the template?

I have a consuming, or main, page, thus:

```dart
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="aplaceontheinterweb" />
    <link rel="import" href="ponies.html" />
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="defined_in_the_included_file">
        ...
    </div>    
    <div is="a-pony"></div>
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and a template, thus:

```html
<polymer-element name="a-pony" extends="div">
    <template>
        <div class="defined_in_the_css_file_referenced_in_main_html">
            ....
        </div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and the `<div>` in the `a-pony` element is not styled appropriately when the page is rendered.

I've seen the demo stuff and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351110/how-do-i-style-elements-in-dart-web-ui-templates?rq=1), but these are specific to styles that are declared inside the template, and don't cover the case where the styles are external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the crucial piece of information I didn't mention in the question is that the styles i'm attempting to apply are in Twitter Bootstrap, and specifically the bootstrap css file is loaded via a cdn.

The resolution is a combination of Alan's answer, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351618/bootstrap-js-not-working-in-polymer-components). I had to bring the bootstrap file into a local copy, rather than pulling in from a cdn, and load author styles via code (as per Alan's code), *not* via markup.

**Edit**

Seth Ladd has helpfully added some bootstrap specific stuff to his [Polymer samples](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/custom_element_with_bootstrap_css) repo on Github, cheers Seth.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding apply-author-styles in code:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag("a-pony")
class APony extends PolymerElement {
  void created(){
    super.created();
    var root = getShadowRoot("a-pony");
    root.applyAuthorStyles = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still a nope. Must be something i'm fundamentally doing wrong.

Comment: Check your css definition. I've run into problems when the css definition involves descendant classes spanning the DOM and the Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set apply-author-styles in order to tell the component to use the page CSS:

```html
<polymer-element name="a-pony" extends="div" apply-author-styles>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but doing this had no effect; I get the same result as before.