# How to skip the Shadow DOM (and use the Light DOM) instead for Polymer templates

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Sometimes you may want to skip the Shadow DOM completely with Polymer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force your Polymer Element's template into the Light DOM by overriding `parseDeclaration` on your `Polymer()` JS/Coffeescript declaration.

**Coffeescript Example:**

```
Polymer "my-element",

  parseDeclaration: (elementElement) ->
    @lightFromTemplate(@fetchTemplate(elementElement))
```

Of course, you have to be careful because if you have anything that belongs in the Shadow DOM (like a stylesheet) in your template, it will now be in the Light DOM.

Edit: If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Just to know...What would be a use case for this? could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, I was using this to test [hacking Select2 into a Polymer element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887814/polymer-select2-element/26701948#26701948).  It needed to get the offset of the Select2 element but the Shadow DOM always returned 0.