# How to use MathJax inside polymer dart element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, mathjax

I am trying to use MathJax inside a polymer.dart element:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Update: Using this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"myDivWithMath"]);
```

Comment: Have you read this article? https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/ There is also progress on creating a new higher level package, but I'm not sure if it's done yet: https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop

Comment: This doesnt solve his issue. As MathJax queries for text nodes in document.body as I guess and MathJax doesnt know about ShadowDom. @John Try to find a function that parses the contents of a HTML Element. Then query for it and start parsing manually.

Comment: @Robert I need to use this: MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"myDivWithMath"]); But I do not know how to call  it from inside polymer element... or it simply can not operate inside the shadow dom?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

MathJax very probably tries to find the element by using `querySelector('myDivWithMath')` which doesn't work because this selector doesn't find the element.

You can try

```dart
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"* /deep/ myDivWithMath"]);
```

don't use shadowDOM by adding the attribute 'lightdom' to the element. This is the only reference I found how to do this [How to skip the Shadow DOM (and use the Light DOM) instead for Polymer templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702025) (never used this myself yet).