# Recommendation for a datetime picker within a web component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, polymer

I am creating a web component that needs to include the capability to choose a specific date and time and am having difficulties locating a datetime picker that can be used within a Polymer-based web component.

**Things I have tried** 
I have attempted to [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jQuery-based Timepicker and [this](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) Bootstrap-based Datetime picker within my component; however, both jQuery and Boostrap are not "shadow-root" aware do not work well with being integrated within a web component. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824828/binding-jqueryui-datepicker-within-a-polymer-web-component) SO article discusses a datetime picker; however, when I select a date, I receive the following error: `Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker`.

I have also attempted to use [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/); however, I cannot located where to place the `webshim.polyfill()` call. (I have tried placing it outside of the Polymer function as well as each of the [Polymer callbacks](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods) without success)

**Question** 
Are there workarounds that would allow the above approaches to work or does anyone have a recommendation on a different datetime picker that is web-component friendly?

Answer (score -1):

I use this [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

Easy Set Up:

```
  <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
     <input id="date" class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
     <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Easy to get Date value:

```
document.getElementById("date").value
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I don't believe it supports choosing a time which is a requirement. Can you clarify?

Comment: The OP stated that `time` is a requirement