# Using bootstrap in polymer element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer

I'm trying to use bootstrap within a polymer element. I'm importing the boostrap js file into my index.html. After that I'm trying to use a bootstrap dropdown in a polymer element.

I created a jsfiddle http://goo.gl/yioAj8

which demonstrates the problem. The dropdown works fine outside the polymer element. But within it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18363226/274673.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap.js not working in Polymer components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351618/bootstrap-js-not-working-in-polymer-components)

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the polymer.html via a link tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">
```

And I've updated to match the Polymer 1.0 syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/98t2zzgm/